# Are all "actions" considered to be a type of "conditions"?

Tags: logic, terminology, definitions, classification

Are all "actions" considered to be a type of "conditions"? Let's take the following sentence:

> "Each display and local field can contain one or more rules that
> contain **a set of conditions and a set of actions** that are applied to
> records when all conditions are met for the rule. Each action within a
> rule can be performed on a single field, and it is performed in the
> order in which it appears in the rule."

I was reading this somewhere and I thought to myself don't conditions include actions? It might seem like a trivial question, but I was thinking the sentence should have been reworded as "a set of conditions, among which conditions based on actions". Is this a nothingburger or am I onto something?

Comment: How can conditions (which are inert abstractions expressed by sentences) be actions (which are causally active and concrete)?

Comment: but actions can be described passively: "you need to kill a gremlin in order to open the chess".

Comment: Anything can be described passively, it does not mean that everything is a description.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.